# Error: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Tags: java, android

Every time i click onClickCreateButton i get this in return:
*android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1*

**Main Activity** class is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText mInput;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    LinearLayout linearLayout2;
    LinearLayout linearLayout3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mInput = findViewById(R.id.EditText);
        linearLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout2);
        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout3 = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linearLayout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayout2.addView(linearLayout3);
    }

    public void onClickCreateButton(View v) {
        LinearLayout temp;
        try {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), linearLayout2.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (linearLayout2.getChildCount() <= 8) {
                temp = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(linearLayout2.getChildCount());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (temp.getChildCount() <= 3) {
                    Button button = new Button(this);
                    button.setText(mInput.getText().toString());
                    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    linearLayout3.addView(button);
                } else {
                    linearLayout3 = new LinearLayout(this);
                    linearLayout3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    linearLayout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    linearLayout2.addView(linearLayout3);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

activity_main:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

It would be of great help is someone could point out the mistake in my code. Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
> ```

`temp.getChildCount()` returns an `int` and the `Toast.makeText()` overload that takes an `int` argument there expects it to be a resource id. Use the `String` overload instead by converting the `int` to a string, e.g.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + temp.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Same issue with the other `Toast`.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to show a number by calling [the version of `Toast.makeText` that takes a resource ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int)):

```java
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), temp.getChildCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You should convert it to a string:

```java
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(temp.getChildCount()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```